# Class inheritance of template parameters in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am new to C++ and happen to come across a code which looks like this :

```
template<class T, class Composite> class CompositeTester: public Composite
{
  public: 
    CompositeTester(T* instance, const typename Composite::Parameters& parameters) : Composite(parameters)
    {
        singletonInstances_[parameters.instanceIndex] = instance;
    }
}
```

1. The inheritance is not so clear to me, because the inheritance is from the template class arguments itself. What is this concept known as?
2. In the contructor `CompositeTester`, I realise that the instance of `Composite` is created with `parameters` as arguments.  But this syntax is quite difficult to understand `const typename Composite::Parameters`. How to intrepret this syntax? Is defining an object of class composite, even before it exists valid?
3. `singletonInstances_[parameters.instanceIndex] = instance`. Is here a new variable created  for `parameters.instanceIndex` ? There exists no definition in the source code for `class Composite::Parameters` or `class Composite`apart from what I mentioned in the question here.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is known as the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4173254).
2. `typename` is used here to denote a dependent type name.  Without it, the compiler will parse the qualified name as a non-type entity.  See our FAQ on this: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245)
3. This is ill-formed in standard C++ because `singletonInstances_` is not declared.  If it is declared in the base class, you need to use `this->` to make it a dependent name.

Comment: I do not really understand this term: `typename Composite::Parameters& parameters`. The :: is a scope resolution operator.  So is `parameters` an object of `Parameters` of type `Composite`  and the reference is being passed?

Comment: `parameters` is a reference to the type `Parameters` which is declared in the scope of the (class) type `Composite`.  (References aren't objects, and I'm not sure what you mean by "an object of `Parameters`")